# Running a loop to check If undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm running a loop to check if `undefined` and if so set it as `zero`

```
            for(var g = 0; g < filtererdData.length; ++g) {
                if(filtererdData[g].positive == undefined) {
                    filtererdData[g].positive == "0";
                }
                console.log(filtererdData[g].positive);
```

but in console I still get undefined for some values, what am I doing wrong or I can triple check if it is really undefined?

Comment: Assignment operation is done with a single ```=```, not ```==```.

Comment: When using `filtererdData[g].positive == "0";`. you are checking for equality. You would want to assign with a single `=`, e.g. `filtererdData[g].positive = "0";`

Comment: @Pim oh right! I'm getting confused on the use of = or == and === all the time

Comment: down votes are really helpful, thanks

Comment: I downvote, because this issue should not arrive at SO, when proper effort is done. In such a short snippet, if you search for five minutes, and test a bit, you should almost always find the issue yourself. Apart from that, any semi-decent development environment should notice this error automatically, as such a comparison inside an ExpressionStatement rarely ever makes sense (and would be bad style, if it actually did something).

Comment: @ASDFGerte are you sending to RTM every user on stackoverflow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if(!filtererdData[g].positive) {
    filtererdData[g].positive = 0; //there was also mistake as pointed out in comments
}
```

This will check if it's [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)

if doing in that way then you should check like this

```
if(typeof filtererdData[g].positive == "undefined")
```

because in JS, undefined if type

Comment: why should I check if not? I want to convert whatever value is undefined to zero

Comment: @MarkBaijens is my comment correct then?

Comment: typeof is unnecessary here

Comment: @MarkBaijens, `if(!filtererdData[g].positive)` will check if the value is "falsy" like "undefined"

Comment: @rob.m if you only want to check on `undefined` then it's not needed do do it like this. However depending on the use case it's often considered best practise to check on `falsy`. As others pointed out your mistake was in the assignment operator.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen should I simply use if(!filtererdData[g].positive) then?

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen Correct but you stated it checks on `undefined`, `null` or `empty`. Falsy is more then that. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: then rest of the code as it is, 

`filtererdData[g].positive = "0";`

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen thanks a lot, accepting as soon as it lets me to

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen should not that "0" be just 0 to be considered as a number? The rest of the values are numbers, is that not a string?

Comment: That doesn't even treat the real problem in the OP! `if(filtererdData[g].positive == undefined)` is perfectly fine to check against `undefined`.

Comment: @rob.m, it's up to you, logically it should be 0 instead of "0"